# Html button who can load/fire multiple JS/button in each div

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a page with little squares generated by a template page, each square has a button which adds a song to a playlist.

In the header I want to make a button to add all of the songs to the playlist, effectively clicking all of them,

<sub>p.s. English is not my main language</sub>

I've worked on this here is my link and code  :

```
 <input type=button id = button2 value=boy onclick="changeMe(this)">
 <input type=button id = button2 value=boy onclick="changeMe(this)">

 <input type=button  value=all onclick="clickall()">

<script>        
function changeMe(obj){
   if(obj.value == "boy"){
   obj.value = "girl"
   }else{
   obj.value = "boy"
  }
}

 function clickall() 
{
    var test = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(i=0;i<test.length;i++)
    {
       if(test[i].value=="boy" || test[i].value=="girl") 
        {
           test[i].click();
        } 
    }


}

</script>
```

JSlink : http://jsfiddle.net/bHK58/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine a way to identify the button.  For example, if your page looks like this:

```
<header> ... </header>
<section id="songs">
    <button>...</button>
    <button>...</button>
    <button>...</button>
</section>
```

... then you could get a list of buttons with:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("songs").getElementsByTagName("button");
```

Then loop through the buttons, and call `button.click()`.

Comment: Ok i worked on this and succes ! thanks a lot !  here a link of final  http://jsfiddle.net/bHK58/2/